# Detecting changes in device security

Tags: android, keystore, public-key

I am working on an app that uses Key Store Keys to enable authentication with the server. When the user logs in I am creating a key pair that requires Authentication to be used either by fingerprint or device credentials.

The problem I have is that I am trying for the keys to get invalidated every time the user changes the security in his device either by enrolling fingerprints or changing the PIN/PASSWORD/PATTERN.

I know that the Key specs have the [setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(boolean)) method but from what I read it only invalidates the keys if there's a change in the biometrics, that doesn't help me if the user is only using device credentials. Furthermore, that method was added on API 24 and I am targetting devices starting with API 23.

This is the way I am creating the keys:

```
       //Purposes of the key
        int keyPurp =
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT |
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY;

        //Init a builder for the key.
        KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder keyBuilder = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(keyAlias,keyPurp)
        //We set the valid formats of the digests for signing
        keyBuilder.setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512);

        //Require the user to authenticate and session expiry
        keyBuilder.setUserAuthenticationRequired(true);
        keyBuilder.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(10);
        KeyGenParameterSpec keySpec = keyBuilder.build();


        //Initialize the generator of the keys
        generator.initialize(keySpec);

        //Get the keys
        generator.generateKeyPair();
```

Is there any Android API to detect changes in the Pin/Pattern/Password configuration?

Comment: The `setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment` method was added to allow developers to say that they DON'T want the keys they generate to get invalidated by new biometric enrollments. The default was, and is, that the keys will get invalidated. As for the pin/password/pattern, I don't know if you can detect when they are changed. But you can at least use the `KeyguardManager`'s `isDeviceSecure` method to check if pin/password/pattern is in use as the device lock.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for the `isInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment` and `setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment`.

`isInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment`

Returns true if the key is irreversibly invalidated when a new biometric is enrolled or all enrolled biometrics are removed. This has effect only for keys that require biometric user authentication for every use.

^ Important part is the last bit `has effect only for keys that require biometric user authentication for every use.`

`setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment`

Sets whether this key should be invalidated on biometric enrollment. This applies only to keys which require user authentication (see setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean)) and if no positive validity duration has been set (see setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(int), meaning the key is valid for biometric authentication only.

^ Important part there is `if no positive validity duration has been set`.

So if you want your keys to be invalidated by changes to biometry, they cannot have a duration attached to them. They must be single use.

We have noticed the keys actually cannot be used even if they have validity duration set to them, but you do not get correct Exception. And you cannot tell difference between a usage outside of duration period or if the key is invalidated.